# How does Garrett Lisi's $E_8$ Theory contain the Higgs Boson and Graviton?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, higgs, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

How does Garrett Lisi's ["Exceptionally Simple Theory of Everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Exceptionally_Simple_Theory_of_Everything) contain the Higgs Boson and Graviton? Let's say that $E_8$ breaks down like this:
$$E_8 \rightarrow E_6 \times SU(3).$$
Then the representations breaks down like this:
$$248 \rightarrow (78,1) \oplus (27,3) \oplus (27,3) \oplus (1,8).$$
The first representation contains the gauge bosons of $E_6$ the second and third one contains the fermions and anti-fermions multiplied by the 3 generations. The last one contains the bosons of the $SU(3)$ which act on generation number.

As you can see, there are no representations for the Higgs bosons nor for the graviton(s).

My best guess is that Lisi didn't consider this form of symmetry breaking. (However most $E_8$ GUTs have incorporated this symmetry breaking pattern as it has Family Symmetry and contains $SO(10)$ and the the Georgi-Glashow and Pati-Salam models.) So my question is how does all elementary particles, including the Higgs and gravitons, fit into $248$.

Edit:
Follow-up questions

1. How does Garrett Lisi's $E_8$ breaks down to the standard model
2. How does the $E_6 \times SU(3)$ group break down through $SO(10)$, the Pati-Salam Model or the Minimal left-right symmetric model.

Edit 2: I've decided to put the follow up questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/795915/follow-up-question-on-garrett-lisis-e-8-toe-related-to-symmetry-breaking)

Comment: I am not an expert on these topics, but there is a paper by Distler and Garibaldi arguing that Lisi's E8 theory cannot work on representation theory grounds that you may find interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2658. From what I understand, Lisi showed it was possible to embed one generation of fermions into E8 with his scheme, but Distler and Garibaldi argued that you could never get three chiral families.

Comment: Alright I'll check it out

Comment: Since Lisi's theory has not been published in a peer-reviewed journal, this does not qualify as a question about mainstream physics.

Comment: Despite the dubious status of Lisi's work I think this is still fine as a question about physics.