# Question about $E_8$ symmetry breaking and hypercharge formula

Tags: group-theory, symmetry-breaking, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

Most $E_8$ gauge theories follow this breaking chain:

$$E_8 \rightarrow E_6 \times SU(3)_{Gen}.$$

How does the $E_6 \times SU(3)$ group break down through $SO(10)$, the Pati-Salam Model or the Minimal left-right symmetric model. (More importantly, how does the $SU(3)_{Gen}$ group breakdown and at what stage.) And also, how is the hypercharge calculated?

From Pati-Salam its:

$$Y = T^R_3 + \frac{B-L}{2}$$

Any answer (whether you answer 1 or 2 of the questions) is appreciated.

Edit: An elaboration is much needed.

Firstly, $E_6$ breaks down like:

$$E_6 \rightarrow SO(10) \times U(1)_A$$

What is this new abelian charge A (I chose A as a label arbitrarily) and how(if it does) does it contribute to weak hypercharge?

Secondly, $SU(3)_{Gen}$ breaks down into 2 $U(1)$s for the 3rd and 8th generator. However I am unsure if this it correct and also how will it be broken.

Comment: Since Lisi's theory has not been published in a peer-reviewed journal, this does not qualify as a question about mainstream physics.

Comment: Despite the dubious status of Lisi's work I think this is still fine as a question about physics.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/795677/2451